# browser is not responding while making $http service call in angular js

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, http

In my project i am using front is Angular JS and Service layer am using Java and DB am using Oracle.

While i am making $http service call (RestFull) from Angular JS. It is taking too much time like 3 mins. after that Browser is not responding.

Browser is showing like this. I am using Google Chrome.

[image]

Could you please any one suggest what is the Problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I see a black image. Is there something wrong with the image?

Comment: Have you look in you're dev tools (F12) the operations during you're $http call ?

Comment: The only way the browser "won't respond" is if a *synchronous request* is taking place. If the browser window just 'turns gray' it may be the application of an unwanted 'modal indicator' that makes it *appear* as though the browser "won't response".

Comment: It is turing to gray, nothing wrong in image, just missed the URL. @Sjoerd2228888